# How can I make an element end at container end?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a cool slanted sidebar next to the red part of the page, but I want it to end at the end of its parent element, so that it doesn't reach into the blue part. How can I do that?

My code does not seem to work on this site, but if you insert it on W3Schools or some other page, it will work. Here is the code I have so far:

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

main {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

article {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.sideBox {
  position: relative;
  height: 200%;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 20%;
  background-color: white;
  transform: rotate(-20deg)
}
```

```html
<!--Font-->
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Turret+Road:800&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">

<main style="background-color:red; ">
  <div class="sideBox">
  </div>
</main>
<article style="background-color:blue"></article>
```

Comment: The code isn't working in those places because there's no content in some of the elements. Also, I think what you're looking for is the CSS `overflow: hidden;`, which you should apply to the element you don't wish to have overflow showing. You might also look at [changing the point of rotation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not a perfect way to make it end exactly where the blue article starts, but you can hide it behind the blue article.  Give your article a z-index and a position of relative, then make the sidebox just long enough, like 110%;

```
position:relative;
z-index: 999;
```

Comment: Thanks dude, something like this was exactly what I was looking for.